# How to use Switch controller based on number of iteration complete

Tags: jmeter

Using Switch controller i need to execute different requests. My requirement is, Request 1 has to execute only one time. After 10 mins my request 2 has to execute. I have configured Switch controller value as 1 it will run request 1. I want to know how to change the switch controller value as 2 after request 1 has completed 1 iteration during the load test.

```
Switch controller 
     -> Once only controller
          .-> request 1
     -> Transaction controller
           -> Request 2
```

I have tried JMeter preprocessors to modify the switch value but it
s not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have Switch Controller there at all.

JMeter executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) **upside down** so it will always run:

1. request 1
2. Request 2

and will run "Request 2" only when "request 1" is finished.

If your question is some kind of "academic" interest: yes, you can use a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) as the "Switch value" but:

1. If you want to provide a numeric index - they are zero-based, in other words you need to put `0` to run 1st child, `1` to run 2nd child, etc.
2. You can amend the variable in various ways:

   - Using a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) like [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) which will extract something from the response somewhere inside the Switch Controller and overwrite the variable value there
   - Using a special sampler like [Set Variables Action](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager))
   - Using any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following code:

     ```
     vars.put('your-variable-name-here', 'your-variable-value-here')
     ```

If the variable doesn't have a default value - nothing will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Switch statement reason my request 1 should not execute more than once like login..